# Is $\delta Q – \delta W$ a state function?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work, definition

I know that internal energy, $Q+W$ is a state function. 
But
$$dU=\delta Q-\delta W,$$
is the change in internal energy, where $dU$ is change in internal energy, $\delta Q$ is the heat supplied to the system and $\delta W$ is the work done by the system. Is this a state function too?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.   Do you mean: given two states is the difference in energy dependent only on the states?

Comment: Im asking whether 'change' in internal energy is a state function.

Comment: You just repeated the question.  You are going to have to explain yourself in more detail.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Whether the change in U is dependent only on the states

Comment: The change in U is dependent only on the initial and final thermodynamic equilibrium states.  This is a requirement of a state function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quantity $dU=\delta Q-\delta W$ is not a state function simply because it is not a function, it is a [differential of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function). In that case a differential of the state function $U$.

The fact that there is a function $U$ such that the differential $\delta Q-\delta W$ is the differential of $U$ means that the differential is exact or $U$ is a state function, i.e., it has a definite value for every point in the space of configuration. In another words, the change in energy depends only on the initial and final states.