# Clarification on the first law of thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

As I understand it, the first law of thermodynamics

$$
     \text{d}Q = \text{d}U + p\text{d}V - \mu \text{d}N
$$

is equivalent to saying: $Q$ is a differentiable real valued function of $U,V$ and $N$, so that we can write $\text{d}Q = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial U}\text{d}U + \frac{\partial Q}{\partial V}\text{d}V + \frac{\partial Q}{\partial N}\text{d}N$, and $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial U}=1$. Also, we define $p=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial V}$ and $-\mu=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial N}$.

Is that it?

Comment: No, $dQ$ is not the exact differential of some function $Q$.

Comment: @Diracology oh... So what is it? (mathematically)

Comment: It's a "differential" whose value depends on the path, I'd say.

Comment: $dQ$ is an inexact differential and it just represents an infinitesimal quantity. However, it is not the differential of some function $Q$. If there was such function, then $Q$ would be a state function and the heat exchanged would depend only on the initial and final states regardless the process taken. Of course this is not the case, heat depends on processes. The same can be said about the infinitesimal work $dW$. On the other hand, $dU$ is in fact a [differential of a function](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/319236/is-delta-q-delta-w-a-state-function/319241#319241) $U$.

Comment: @FGSUZ the problem is the exact meaning of "differential"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So yes, an expression like $$\delta f = g(x,y)~dx + h(x,y)~dy,$$is somewhat hard to parse at first. It means that there is some quantity which you care about defined by the integral, $$f = \int_0^1 ds~g\big(x(s), y(s)\big)~\frac{dx}{ds}+\int_0^1 ds~h\big(x(s), y(s)\big)~\frac{dy}{ds},$$where the system takes a path $s \mapsto [x(s), y(s)]$ from $s=0$ at the start to $s=1$ at the end. I hope you can appreciate why we would like to write it the above way! The actual expression is very complicated, the compact way above is much simpler.

Sometimes, the expressions one gets are integrable and have a "path independence" to them. For example if I tell you that $df = y~dx + x~dy$ you might be able to see that this is an exact differential for $f(x, y) = x~y + C.$ Usually in physics we just look for commuting partial derivatives, so ${\partial g \over \partial y} = {\partial h \over \partial x},$ to give this integrability property. So an example which does not work is that if one wrote $y~df = y^2~dx + x~y~dy$, those partial derivatives are no longer equal; one is $\frac12 y$ and the other is $y$. So now $\delta q = y~df$ is not an exact differential implying a state function, even though $df$ is. Now let's run that argument backwards.

Let's define $r = \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial h}{\partial x},$ then multiplying through by some factor $p$ causes $r \mapsto p~r(x, y) + g(x, y)\frac{\partial p}{\partial y} - h(x, y)\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}.$ In pretty general circumstances one can imagine that we find some $p$ which sets this to 0 (it's just a linear first-order PDE), and then we know that even if $\delta f$ was not an exact differential, $p~\delta f$ is.

At least for reversible processes we define the entropy change $dS = dQ/T,$ this is precisely what we are attempting to do with that first law; we are multiplying through by $1/T$ to find an exact state function $S$ for the system, which we call the entropy. (For irreversible processes the work one gets back out is strictly lower than the maximum one could get, and so there is also a "lost work" term in the expression.) It may not be completely obvious that $T$ should be the temperature, but one can derive that if the $S$ for a closed system is restricted to increase, and that closed system is made up of two coupled systems sharing energy, then the one with higher $T$ spontaneously sends energy to the one with lower $T$ in order to increase $S$ -- this gives a physical intuition based on the idea that this state function should always be increasing.

Comment: So it seems that you're saying that $f$ is a function which takes a path/curve as argument and outputs a real number. The way that $f$ is defined is expressed by the notation with $d$'s. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, the default in such expressions is some sort of path-dependent quantity, and we often use a symbol other than $d$ to remind ourselves that, say, since engines are possible a system may have returned to the exact same state but the net work extracted might be nonzero. But we often also get very interested in the case where the differential is exact and therefore the integral only depends on the start and end points.

Answer (score 1):

No, because $\delta Q$ is an [inexact differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inexact_differential), meaning it's path dependent. Also, if it were true that, e.g., $\partial Q/\partial U =1$, than a change in internal energy $U$ would always correspond to exchanged heat $Q$, what's of course not true (i.e., there exist adiabatic processes).